# Installation 2SexyContent in Dnn Portal (dnnSoftware)

Tags: installation, 2sxc, dnn9

When I install **2sxc** in **DnnSoftware** in recent versions I got the following error message.
My provider has SQL Server switch to "czech_CI_AS" I can´t this change to US-language.
Does anyone have advice?

**SqlDataProvider**

```
Info Created - SqlDataProvider\00.99.00.SqlDataProvider
Info Executing 00.99.00.SqlDataProvider
Info Start Sql execution: 00.99.00.SqlDataProvider file
Failure SQL Execution resulted in following Exceptions: System.Data.
SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Your SQL installation is non-standard
using a Custom Object Qualifier. 2sic uses the standard Microsoft Entity
Framework which doesn't work well with this feature - installation aborted.
**Changed language setting to us_english**. at System.Data.SqlClient.
SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection,
Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.
OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1
wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser...
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have installed DNN with a custom "qualifier". The default is `dbo` but the install dialog allows you to change it. it's an old feature meant to "share" a sql for multiple customers. 2sxc can't be installed in this setup - sorry :(

Comment: Great, in the new installation I set the default value and 2sxc works. Thank you for your help.